# How to run AspNet.SignalR application as a stand alone service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I would like to use AspNet.SignalR for connecting UI with server login. Yet I would prefer to host AspNet.SignalR server as a stand alone, UI less server, while hosting web UI as a saparate project/serverless code. Is it possible and what are basic steps to acheive such configuration: two projects one for server logic and one for client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OWIN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3) to host an asp.net application as a windows service